# SSRS: Upload multiple reports to reporting server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

Is it possible to upload multiple RDL files in Report Manager?

For example: I have 40 rdl files in a folder and I want to upload all these 40 RDLs in a single upload (i.e as a zip or just the whole folder).

Normally I have to upload these RDLs one by one and that takes too long and increases the chance of an error.

Answer (score 2):

If all the RDLs exist in one project, you can deploy it to the server via Visal Studio.

[Here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/sql-server-reporting-services-basics-deploying-reports/) is a guide

Comment: Visual Studio always gives us compatibility problems. So we only use Reporting Builder...

Comment: Visual Studio is the best solution, if you have issues, it's probably better to fix those rather than leave yourself with a workaround that is not productive.

Comment: The only way to fix the issues we have, is going to every rdl file, open them as xml and edit them hard coded. So I was hoping for a better solution because this way it takes the same time...